# Executing slot on every application's event loop iteration

Tags: c++, qt, event-loop, qeventloop

How can I call my slot on every iteration of application's event loop?
Only way I know is to use QTimer and on every timeout (every millisecond) signal I can call my slot.
But I don't like this option, it looks like workaround.

Any suggestions how to do this more correctly?

Comment: Your QTimer can have a timeout of 0, which will run once per event loop instead of once per millisecond, which will only *probably* run once per event loop. :-)  Still a bit of a workaround, though.

Comment: Yes, I know this and I am using it now, but it is not what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Qt 4.7 QCoreApplication::exec() documentation:

> To make your application perform idle
>   processing (i.e. executing a special
>   function whenever there are no pending
>   events), use a QTimer with 0 timeout.
>   More advanced idle processing schemes
>   can be achieved using processEvents().

So your approach is what is prescribed. Look at QCoreApplication::processEvents() for more control over the event loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could also take a look at using the installEventFilter method on QCoreApplication::instance() object. This would allow you access to ALL events before they were processed for all widgets in your application.