# Insert Event in Qt's event loop without using QTimers

Tags: qt, event-handling, exec, while-loop

I am looking for a way to insert a call to my function or a slot with every looping of the Qt's event loop. I know there exists a solution using QTimers which is prescribed by Qt but they also say it is possible by calling processEvents(). Does that mean that I don't call exec at all and do the following?

```
while(true)
{
// My processing code
//  blah blah
qApp.processEvents();
}
```

I believe this is not what they meant. Does anyone have more idea on how to do this using the processEvents() approach?

This question is similar to 
[Executing slot on every application's event loop iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124282/executing-slot-on-every-applications-event-loop-iteration)
but I am looking for something completely without timers.

Any references or links are very much appreciated.
Best,

CV

Comment: You didn't say _why_ you don't want to use timers.  A timer of 0 interval seems like it should be the right tool, can you explain why you don't want to use it?

Comment: The processEvents() method is to be called while Qt's event loop is running. You can use it to keep your UI responsive while you are doing a long calculation within the GUI thread. So it's not what you want, I guess...

Comment: The Qt docs say "To make your application perform idle processing (i.e. executing a special function whenever there are no pending events), use a QTimer with 0 timeout." So why isn't this sufficient?

Comment: If you really want complete control you could indeed use processEvents() method. Just do the loop as you wrote it but make sure it is executed with Qt's event loop.